# Use fields of announcement list in attached word document

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any Chance to use fields of an announcement list to fill in blank fields in an attached word dokument?

I managed to do so in a document library by activating contenttypes in the list and adding build in document properties in the world dokument.

Answer (score 0):

By design, SharePoint list not supports add build in document properties in the **attachments**.

By default, **SharePoint list is not a document library** and, as a result, lacks all the document management features of a document library, like versioning, check-in/check-out, co-authoring, ability to open and edit documents in the browser, etc.

Since **attachments** just sit together attached to an item, **there is no way to organize them in folders or apply file-specific metadata** (like you can in the document library).